# Is it possible for a popup window to appear after a validation rule returns false?

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, validation

We need a validation rule to check if a entered value is not twice as large as the average of the last three years. If the validation rule returns false, there should be a popup window displaying the error message and a link to send an email to the user who entered the invalid data?

Does anyone know if this is possible? And second how would we go about implementing this logic?

Comment: Validation rules stop execution entirely. More likely, you're looking for a trigger to accomplish this, since you apparently don't want to stop the entire flow. Also, Visualforce will be needed for a custom popup like this (at least, for now... see [Warning messages](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC) for one possible idea).